# Using FormatFilter attribute within mvc core 2.1.3 API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, autofac

I'm facing som difficulties getting the `[FormatFilter]` to work in my MVC Core 2.1.3 API. 
I want my endpoint to support JSON and XML, so I wrote this code:

`Startup` class, which inherits from a `StartupCore` class:

```
public class Startup : StartupCore
{
    protected override void OnConfigure(
        IApplicationBuilder app,
        IHostingEnvironment env,
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
        IApplicationLifetime appLifetime) => AutoMappings.Initialize();
}
```

And (partially) this `StartupCore` class

```
//....
services
    .AddCors()
    .AddMvcCore()
    .AddApiExplorer()
    .AddJsonFormatters()
    .AddXmlSerializerFormatters() //With or without this line; no luck
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter());
    })
    .AddMvcOptions(options =>
    {
        options.InputFormatters.Add(new PlainTextInputFormatter());
        options.OutputFormatters.Add(new CsvOutputFormatter());
        options.FormatterMappings.SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat("csv", MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/csv"));
        options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());
        options.FormatterMappings.SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat("xml", MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/xml"));
    })
//.......
```

When I use the `FormatFilter` attribute on my controller like

```
[HttpGet]
[FormatFilter]
[Route("/public/feed/{format}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateFeed(string format)
{
    //
}
```

I'm getting the error: **Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException: The requested service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.FormatFilter' has not been registered.**

However when I use the `Produces` attribute it gives me XML data.

```
[HttpGet]
[Produces("application/xml")]
[Route("/public/feed/{format}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateFeed(string format)
{
    //
}
```

I could end up with two endpoints; one for JSON and one for XML but I rather have one endpoint with the `FormatFilter`.

So what am I missing here?

**WORKAROUND**: For now I'm using the `Produces` attribute `[Produces("application/json", "application/xml"]`

Source used: https://andrewlock.net/formatting-response-data-as-xml-or-json-based-on-the-url-in-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If endpoint or controller uses FormatFilter attribute then the corresponding service should be registered via AddFormatterMappings:

```
services.AddMvcCore()
...
.AddFormatterMappings()
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `StartupCore`, you're relying on the `OnMvcCoreServiceConfiguration` event to add your XML output formatter. That is going to trigger on the line where you you call `AddMvcCore`. Then, later, you call `AddMvcOptions` again, which is going to override the previous call you made. In that second call, you don't add the XML formatter, so it never actually gets added.

You need to pay attention to the asynchronous nature of what's happening. You're passing an action that will be called at some point in the app startup, so the first time time you call `AddMvcOptions`, nothing is actually happening with that yet. When you later call it again, you're setting a new action that it will use eventually, replacing the one you set previously.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, at gave some ideas to fix. Although I'm still unsuccessful on this. I updated my question to the current situation, but still get the same error

Comment: AddMvcOptions doesn't override the previous call, it just adds additional configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem with my .Net Core 2.1 WebAPI project and discovered that I needed to explicitly set the "Accept" Request Header as part of my Ajax call. Within my original .Net 4.7 Web API project setting the dataType property to either 'json' or 'xml' was enough for the correct content type to be returned but it appears not for .Net Core. My Ajax call is as per below:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    beforeSend: function (request)
    {
        request.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
        // or for json request.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    },
    traditional: true,
    url: uri,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'xml',
    // or for json dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data)
    {
        ...
    },
    error: function (req, status, err)
    {
        ...
    }
});
```

I also needed to prevent caching to ensure the correct Accept header was passed to my  controller method each time by setting the NoStore property within the ResponseCache decorator:

```
    [ResponseCache(NoStore = true)]
    public ActionResult Get(string customerName)
    {
       ...
    }
```